# How to fix Vignetting?

Tags: image-processing

Such as this [photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting):

[image]

I want to remove the dark corner to get this result:

[image]

I know this is easy to remove in *Photoshop*, but I'm a MMA user so I want to know how to process it with MMA...

Comment: Is that you in the photograph?

Comment: Do you _need_ to do it in Mathematica? AffinityPhoto has a remove vignette and so do other tools. Otherwise, just generate a circular gradient image of the same dimensions (black in the middle to white on the edge) and ImageAdd it to lighten the edges. You'll need to experiment with the radius

Comment: @user1066 The image from the wiki link. :)

Comment: Mathematica has an example of this in the documentation for [BrightnessEqualize](https://wolfram.com/xid/0k77q04868l80-6r7whd) see the section in Scope > Parameters so this is already covered in the docs. Also if you want to go the radial gradient route as I suggested, then there's `RadialGradientImage`.

Comment: That is not how it works. When you have RAW image you have lenses and camera body names in the EXIF metadata and that is used to get optical correction profile. Or optical profile is inside the RAW file if the smart lenses behave more complex, like in Nikon Z 9. See how it works in Rawtherapee and https://discuss.pixls.us/t/reverse-engineering-nikon-z-series-lens-correction/36733/30

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников There is lens profile data in the EXIF: it's present for this particular image which was shot on a Canon EOS 20D_and _VignetteAmount=-100_ and _VignetteMidpoint_ fields are present suggesting extra vignette was added. It will be an unreasonable amount of work to build lens-accurate vignette removal in Mathematica, hence why I suggested the much quicker poor-man's vignette removal, just subtracting a radial gradient.